# Godot test grey screen _physics_process(_delta) issue

Tags: godot, delta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMwHK.png)
Let me also say this is my very first time trying coding so I'm as new as it gets to this.

Im following a youtube guide and have done everything correctly but when I go to test the game it just gives me a blank grey screen and I'm not sure why. I have done every recommendation from the debugger and still nothing. I've tried changing from _delta to just delta and got the same results. Any help would be great!

The _delta should be the correct line to make the game function properly but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: If anyone is having the same issue make sure to add a camera2d to your player node!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).